# Non-Cyclic Subgroup of $GL(2, \mathbb Z)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, cyclic-groups

I'm trying to find an infinite, non-cyclic, subgroup of:

H =$\left \{ \begin{bmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{bmatrix} : a,b,c,d \in \mathbb Z \right\}$

My current thought is to look at the subgroup, 
$K =\left \{ \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} : ad - bc = \pm 1 \right \}$.

I feel that this shouldn't be cyclic, but I'm having a lot of trouble proving that.  I've been trying proof by contradiction, but that seems to go nowhere.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take any two non-commuting elements, one of them of infinite order, of $\;H\;$, and look at the subgroup generated by them . With some luck you could even end with a free group in two generators, which is as non-abelian, leave alone non-cyclic, as you want it.

Comment: Remark : $H$ is NOT $GL(2,\mathbb{Z})$!!

Comment: But $K$ is actually... An invertible $\mathbb{Z}$ matrix need to have an invertible determinant over the integers. $H$ is $\mathcal{M}(2,\mathbb{Z})$.

Answer (score 3):

A cyclic group is abelian. To show that your $K$ is not cyclic, therefore, it is enough to exhibit two of its elements which do not commute.

Answer (score 1):

What about [orders of elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_%28group_theory%29) ?  It is not hard to find in your groups elements of finite order like $- I_2$ and elements of infinite order like $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. That's impossible in a cyclic group.